# dplyr and tidyr - calculating a lot of linear models at once with factors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

After reading more into the tidyverse, I started fitting many linear models at once as described in [this](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/). Namely, I would do something along these lines:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), 
                 x1 = runif(10),
                 x2 = runif(10))

df %>%
  gather(covariate, value, x1:x2) %>% 
  group_by(covariate) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(.x = data , .f = ~lm(y ~ value, data = .))) %>% 
  mutate(rsquared = map_dbl(.x = model, .f = ~summary(.)$r.squared))
```

The problem is that this approach fails when the variables are not of the same type, for example when one is numeric and one is a factor, as the `gather()` function will coerce the whole `value` vector into a factor. For example,

```
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), 
                 x1 = runif(10),
                 x3 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE))

df %>%
  gather(covariate, value, x1:x3) %>% 
  sapply(class)
```

is followed by the warning

```
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped 

          y   covariate       value 
  "numeric" "character" "character"
```

and the `value` column is a character, so the trick with `nest()` will not work any more as all the covariates will be put in as factors.

I am wondering whether there is a *tidy* way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the types when fitting the model, although you should proceed with care as pointed out in the comments as this could have unintended consequences.

If you still want to convert, you could use `type_convert` from *readr* on the entire frame or `type.convert` just on the "value" vector.

Using `type_convert`:

```
mutate(model = map(.x = data , .f = ~lm(y ~ value, data = readr::type_convert(.))))
```

Using `type.convert`:

```
mutate(model = map(.x = data , .f = ~lm(y ~ type.convert(value), data = .)))
```

Either of these as part of the chain lead to the desired result for this case:

```
df %>%
    gather(covariate, value, x1:x3) %>% 
    group_by(covariate) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(model = map(.x = data , .f = ~lm(y ~ type.convert(value), data = .))) %>% 
    mutate(rsquared = map_dbl(.x = model, .f = ~summary(.)$r.squared))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  covariate              data    model   rsquared
      <chr>            <list>   <list>      <dbl>
1        x1 <tibble [10 x 2]> <S3: lm> 0.33176960
2        x3 <tibble [10 x 2]> <S3: lm> 0.06150498
```

Comment: Clever approach. +1

Comment: Will fail if you happen to have numeric-looking variables that are nevertheless supposed to be treated like factors (maybe not a great idea, but it does happen a lot). `gather`ing is inevitably (?) going to lose some information ...